# Using rioxarray clip_box function does not return anything

Tags: rioxarray, xarray, grib-2

I am trying to clip an xarray dataarray (or dataset, either one) to a bounding box using the rioxarray clip_box() function. My dataarray is 24 hours of temperature data for the continental US. My datarray looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 't2m' (time: 24, y: 1059, x: 1799)>
array([[[293.093  , 293.093  , 293.093  , ..., 299.6555 , 299.6555 ,
         299.6555 ],...
 dtype=float32)

Coordinates:
  * time                 (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-01-01 ... 2021-01-01T23:0...
    step                 timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00
    heightAboveGround    float64 2.0
    latitude             (y, x) float64 21.14 21.15 21.15 ... 47.86 47.85 47.84
    longitude            (y, x) float64 237.3 237.3 237.3 ... 299.0 299.0 299.1
    valid_time           (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-01-01 ... 2021-01-01T23:0...
    gribfile_projection  int32 0
Dimensions without coordinates: y, x
Attributes: (12/37)
    GRIB_paramId:                             167
    GRIB_dataType:                            fc
    GRIB_numberOfPoints:                      1905141
    GRIB_typeOfLevel:                         heightAboveGround
    GRIB_stepUnits:                           1
    GRIB_stepType:                            instant
    ...                                       ...
    GRIB_stepRange:                           0
    GRIB_units:                               K
    long_name:                                2 metre temperature
    units:                                    K
    standard_name:                            air_temperature
    grid_mapping:                             gribfile_projection
```

I pull the temperature data using the Herbie library. Because longitude units are from 0-360, I convert the coordinates to be between -180 and 180. My BBOX is over Denver, that's the only data I care about.

```
from herbie import FastHerbie
import rioxarray
import pandas as pd
# Pull data from Herbie
day = '2021-01-01'
hours = pd.date_range(start=day, periods=24, freq="1H",)
FH = FastHerbie(hours, model="hrrr")
ds = FH.xarray("TMP:2 m", remove_grib=False)
temp = ds['t2m']

# min lat, min lon, max lat, max lon
extent = [39.261506, -105.787200, 40.287389, -104.331512]
min_lat = extent[0]
min_lon = extent[1]
max_lat = extent[2]
max_lon = extent[3]

#convert longitude to be betweeen -180 and 180
temp = temp.assign_coords(longitude=(((temp.longitude + 180) % 360) - 180))

# clip box
sub = temp.rio.clip_box(minx=min_lon, miny=min_lat, maxx=max_lon, maxy=max_lat)
```

It runs without error. However, sub is not assigned a variable.
running `sub` in the console returns `NameError: name 'sub' is not defined`

Comment: Also, trying to clip it a different way with `cropped_ds = temp.sel(latitude=slice(min_lat,max_lat), longitude=slice(min_lon,max_lon))` returns `KeyError: "no index found for coordinate 'latitude'"` even though latitude is clearly a key

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "running sub in the console". What happens with you `print(sub)`?

Comment: `NameError: name 'sub' is not defined` It appears that the function is returning null. It's like I should be receiving an error message from the function but I'm not

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: Added the code that pulls the data using the Herbie module.